# Monitoring and restarting docker container (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm looking into ways of deploying, monitoring and restarting (in cause of failure) my docker containers with `docker-compose`, but I can't find anything else than using `swarm`.

Not that `swarm` is bad, but I want to study all the possibilities, pros and cons and then decide.

Are there any other methods for deploying, monitoring and restarting containers that are being ran with `docker-compose`?

Edit: This is for production purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy, monitor or restart containers with docker-compose. You can define [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart) to *always* for production.

You don't have to choose only one for docker-compose and swarm. They are well [integrated](https://docs.docker.com/compose/swarm/). If you run docker compose on a swarm cluster member, swarm will deploy it to cluster.